# Получить размеры python requests

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, requests

есть [ссылка](https://tr.calvinklein.com/kadin-yun-smokin-yakali-kaban-p_188725#size-select), надо получить размеры товара, но без клика на кнопку этого сделать невозможно(как мне кажется). При клике сервер отправляет post запрос, и только тогда появляются размеры. Помогите вытащить эти размеры без selenium если это конечно возможно. Уже всю голову сломал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post запрос

```
import requests

data = {
    'productId': '188725',
    'viewName': 'PSizeSelect',
}
response = requests.post('https://tr.calvinklein.com/Urun/GetDetail', data=data)
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался, надо было ещё куки передать